# Can you use `aws-sdk` to store objects in Google Storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, storage, google-cloud-storage

Google Storage claims they support *interoperability* in their solution with Amazon AWS S3 and Eucalyptus Systems APIs.

<sup>source: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability</sup>

Can the `aws-sdk` for Java, or Node.js, or Python, be used to store and retrieve objects with the Google Storage APIs?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the AWS SDK to store objects within google storage.

From [Simple migration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple):

> In a simple migration from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage, you can
>   use your existing tools and libraries for generating authenticated
>   REST requests to Amazon S3, to also send authenticated requests to
>   Google Cloud Storage. The changes you need to make to your existing
>   tools and libraries are described in this section.
>
> To get set up for a simple migration do the following:
>
> - Set a [default Google project](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#defaultproj).
> - Get a [developer key](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys).
> - In your existing tools or libraries, make the following changes:
>
>   - Change the request endpoint to use the [Cloud Storage request endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints).
>   - Replace the Amazon Web Services (AWS) access and secret key with the corresponding Cloud Storage access key and secret key
>       (collectively called your Google developer key).
>
> That's it! At this point you can start using your existing tools and
>   libraries to send keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC)
>   requests to Google Cloud Storage.
>
> When you use the Cloud Storage XML API in a simple migration scenario,
>   specifying the `AWS` signature identifier in the `Authorization`
>   header lets Cloud Storage know to expect `x-amz-*` headers and Amazon
>   S3 ACL XML syntax in your request.
>
> **Note:** A simple migration from Amazon S3 is an easy and quick way to get started using Google Cloud Storage, with a minimal investment
>   in time and changes to your existing code. After you have some
>   experience with a simple migration, you can fully transition to Google
>   Cloud Storage to take advantage of all its features. For more
>   information, see [Full Migration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-full).

Comment: so sneaky, Google :)

Comment: @pwynne: the downvotes were likely caused by your link-only answer - frowned upon, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 7):

Most of the AWS SDKs mentioned support constructing a custom endpoint, for example as described [here for Node.JS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Endpoint.html).

Setting the endpoint to `storage.googleapis.com` and using your GCP access credentials should enable you to operate the Google storage backend service "like S3".

Comment: Is this just in theory, or does this actually work?